# EF 6 Generated SQL from Skip and Take does not work

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

The sql generated by the `newQuery` does not have the OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

```
    public IList<T> GetManyOrderByDescending<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, Func<T, TProperty> orderBySelector, int page, int pageSize, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var query = includes.Aggregate(DbSet, (current, item) => current.Include(item));

        var newQuery = query.AsExpandable().Where(where).OrderByDescending(orderBySelector).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

        return newQuery.ToList();
    }
```

This is how it is used:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Age < 40);

var list = _customerService.OrderByDescending(predicate, x => x.Name, 1, 10, x => x.CustomerType);
```

Comment: Which EF version, which database provider, and why is `orderBySelector` not an expression?

Comment: @GertArnold EF 6

Comment: The code uses LinqKit, not EF 6. What are you trying to generate and what was generated? Have you tried using EF6 directly? There doesn't seem to be any need for LinqKit here

Comment: Besides, retrieving the first 10 items can be done with `TOP 10`, *BUT* applying TOP 10 or FETCH NEXT 10 to the result of an INNER JOIN will limit all rows. It won't return the first 10 roots or just 10 children. Getting the first 10 roots with all their children would require a more complex SQL query

Comment: Should  `_customerService.OrderByDescending` be `_customerService.GetManyOrderByDescending`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `Func<T, TProperty> orderBySelector` to an expression `Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>` solved the issue. Thanks to @GertArnold's comment